# Authenticate powershell script using AccessToken

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release pipeline which is calling a PowerShell script and it is having 'Select-AzureSubscription' statement (In a loop I have to assign different subscriptions as current and do some process). When it runs, I am getting the below error as I have not added 'Add-AzureAccount'.

Select-AzureSubscription : The subscription name  doesn't exist.

Is there any way to authenticate or execute Add-AzureAccount using the Pipeline access token.

Code:-

```
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $Subscription -Current 
CloudServices = Get-AzureService | select ServiceName
```

Comment: If you care to lookup [Add-AzureAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/add-azureaccount?view=azuresmps-4.0.0), you will find that none of the parameters accept pipeline input, so the answer is No.

Comment: Is there any workaround? to authenticate Select-AzureSubscription

Comment: What azure resources will you access? Could you provide your script snippet? Maybe I can give a better solution.

Comment: Hi Joy,  Edited the question and added the code. Here I want to get all the list of cloud services. For executing the command 'Get-AzureService', we need to set a default subscription. But here, Select-AzureSubscription requires an authentication. How to proceed this authentication though a release pipeline.

Comment: @Tinz Do you use [Azure PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops)? You need an Azure Resource Manager service connection before using Azure resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the steps below(I could not test it for you as I don't have a user account without MFA-enabled).

1.In devops, navigate to the `Project Settings` -> `Service connections` -> `New service connection` -> `Azure Classic`.

[image]

Then input the information, you could get the subscription name and id in the azure portal -> Subscriptions.

**Note:** The `Username` and `Password` need to be the user account without MFA-enabled.

[image]

[image]

2.After creating the service connection, in the pipline, create a Azure powershell task with `Task version 3.*`, select the `Azure Connection Type` with `Azure Classic`, select `Azure Classic Subscription` with the service connection which was created in step 1.

Then use the script:

```
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName <subscription-name> -Current 
CloudServices = Get-AzureService | select ServiceName
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Joy, In this case, do we need a separate Service Connection for each Subscription?

Comment: Hey Joy, In PowerShell I am having a subscription loop and getting Azure services of each subscription. If I can use only one subscription in a pipeline, then I cannot go for this solution. :(

Comment: @Tinz Not sure, you can have a try. If you just use one service connection, see the `Select-AzureSubscription` if works or not. If it does not work, you may need to use different connections. The problem is I don't have the account without MFA, so I cannot test for you.-(

Comment: @Tinz Please have a try, maybe it can.